# Use Avro model from different package in different repository

Tags: java, avro

I have not common problem

I have repository X which contains avro model called Person. In my repository Y, I would like to create a new model with property of type Person from repository X. Is it even possible?

I have imported X artifact to Y but it still has a problem to use it.